# React correct way to use setState((prevState)=>{})

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I just started to learn React.js. Here is a question regarding `setState()`.

My new state is calculated based on my previous state so I use `setState()` as a function that takes `prevState` as a parameter. Please refer to the image below for codes and views.

According to some examples I found online, the `updatedCount` variable is created before calling `setState()` (ex1). My question is: Can I use `prevState` to create `updatedCount` inside `setState()` (ex2). Is it a good practice? If it's not, what's wrong with this approach?

ex1:

```
handleCountChange = (type, v) => {
  const updatedCount = this.state.counters[type] + v; // <--
  this.setState((prev) => {
    return {
      counters: {
        ...prev.counters,
        [type]: updatedCount,
      },
    };
  });
};
```

ex2:

```
handleCountChange = (type, v) => {
  this.setState((prev) => {
    const updatedCount = prev.counters[type] + v; // <--
    return {
      counters: {
        ...prev.counters,
        [type]: updatedCount,
      },
    };
  });
};
```

Full example codes are shown below that intended to update two counters:

[image]

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you for the link. I added the codes to my post.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create variable and process the data before updating the state inside the update state callback.

This used to be pretty common in the `this.setState()` days, and I have done it a lot, because that's the only way to be sure that the data you are getting is up to date with the current context.